# Whenever I kill my app, the service is running but speech to text not working

Tags: java, android, speech-to-text

I created a speech to text app and it's working in the background but whenever I kill my app, the service is running but speech to text not working I want my app service to work properly after killing my app

Comment: What do you mean by "kill my app"? How are you doing that?

Comment: when i suspend my app from background

Comment: What does that mean? How do you do that?

Comment: also, how do you know your `Service` is still running?